# ffmpeg png overlay to mp4 color is not correct

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay some subs on an .mp4 file using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i count5.mp4 -i subs1.png -i subs2.png \
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable=between(t\,1\,2):x=0:y=0[out]; \
[out][2]overlay=enable=between(t\,3.5\,4.6):x=0:y=0[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a? new.mp4
```

It works, but the subtitle colors are not correct:
Here is the overlay:

[image]

Here is how it looks on the .mp4 output:

[image]

Looks like it turned a little pink or orange. Maybe the better question is how do I maintain the correct video quality? I have very limited knowledge of video formats and ffmpeg so not sure where to start debugging or the right keywords to use.

Finder tells me the png is color profile `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` and the video is `HD (1-1-1)`

Here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_FNHpIUdK0bhyg8EJ2OSDJ1-dW_uVDaZ?usp=sharing) to the files

Comment: Is it reproducible with only one overlay stage (instead of overlaying twice)? Can you please share `subs1.png`, `subs2.png` and small part of `count5.mp4` (share using Google Drive for example)?

Comment: @Rotem hi yes, I've updated the question with a link to the files stored in Google Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resembled the issue described in the [following post](https://superuser.com/questions/1757284/ffmpeg-incorrect-colourspace-with-hardcoded-subtitles).

In out case, the pixel format of `subs1.png` and `subs2.png` is RGBA (applies [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) standard with alpha transparency channel).

The pixels format of `count5.mp4` is "limited range" yuv420p in [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) standard.
The output video `new.mp4`, keeps the BT.709 characteristics.
We may see these details using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool.

---

As described in my [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757297/635712), FFmpeg always assume [BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) color characteristics, and doesn't convert to BT.709 when it should.

The solution is converting the color format of the PNG images to BT.709 using [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1) filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i count5.mp4 -i subs1.png -i subs2.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:dst_format=yuva420p[v1];[2]scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:dst_format=yuva420p[v2];[0][v1]overlay=enable=between(t\,1\,2):x=0:y=0[out];[out][v2]overlay=enable=between(t\,3.5\,4.6):x=0:y=0[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a? new.mp4`

---

For getting better text quality, we may avoid [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) and use yuv444 instead of yuv420 (note that I don't know if your target application can handle yuv444 pixel format):

`ffmpeg -y -i count5.mp4 -i subs1.png -i subs2.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:dst_format=yuva444p[v1];[2]scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:dst_format=yuva444p[v2];[0][v1]overlay=enable=between(t\,1\,2):x=0:y=0:format=yuv444[out];[out][v2]overlay=enable=between(t\,3.5\,4.6):x=0:y=0:format=yuv444[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p new.mp4`

---

Examining the color using paint.net:

`subs1.png`:
[image]

Frame from `new.mp4`:
[image]

As we can see, the output has almost the same color values as the input.

Comment: I would never had guessed that you can manage color options with the scale filter....

Comment: thanks, let me try this out, this is some crazy stuff lol